# Web scraping utilizando python

Tags: web-scraping

Gostaria de imprimir todas as divs de determinado site que estão contidas dentro de uma div superior

```
<div class="history-feed__collection">
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">9</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_hearts" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">K</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_diamonds" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">Q</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_clubs" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">2</div></div>
```

Gostaria que o programa listasse pro exemplo "history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades, history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_hearts,... " comecei esse codigo, mas ainda encontro problemas

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chromedriver')

driver.get('https://card.com')

id = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class]')

for ii in id:
    print(ii.get_attribute('class="hilo-history-feed__collection"'))
    
driver.close()
```

Comment: Quais problemas?